# Sign mobileconfig file using certificate programmatically with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, certificate, mobile-config

my question is how to programmatically sign the configuration file before downloading the file from the local server?
I have a file of type .mobileconfig and a certificate file of type .pem with a key received from Zerossl. There are 3 chain certificates

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE——
//some symbols
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE——
//some symbols
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE——
//some symbols
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I manage to sign the certificate locally on the computer using terminal commands, but in my case I need to do it programmatically in Swift inside the app.

Could somebody please help me with it?

Here how to sign the certificate using common line tool: [here](https://www.steveneppler.com/blog/2011/02/09/signing-ios-mobileconfig-files-with-your-certificate) or [here](https://osxdominion.wordpress.com/2015/04/21/signing-mobileconfig-profiles-with-keychain-certificates/)

Comment: Did you get any answer for this?